# How to use Intel Westmere 1GB pages on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, perf

**Edit**: I updated my question with the details of my benchmark

For benchmarking purposes, I am trying to setup 1GB pages in a Linux 3.13 system running on top of two Intel Xeon 56xx ("Westmere") processors. For that I modified my boot parameters to add support for 1GB pages (10 pages). These boot parameters only contain 1GB pages and not 2MB ones. Running `hugeadm --pool-list`  leads to:

```
      Size  Minimum  Current  Maximum  Default
1073741824       10       10       10        *
```

My kernel boot parameters are taken into account. In my benchmark I am allocating 1GiB of memory that I want to be backed by a 1GiB huge page using:

```
#define PROTECTION (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE)
#define FLAGS (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB)
uint64_t size = 1UL*1024*1024*1024;
memory = mmap(0, size, PROTECTION, FLAGS, 0, 0);
if (memory == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(1);
}
sleep(200)
```

Looking at the `/proc/meminfo` while the bench is sleeping (`sleep` call above), we can see that one huge page has been allocated:

```
AnonHugePages:      4096 kB
HugePages_Total:      10
HugePages_Free:        9
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

**Note:** I disabled THP (through the `/sys` file system) before running the bench, so I guess the `AnonHugePages` field reported by `/proc/meminfo` represents the huge pages allocated by THP before stopping it.

At this point we can think that all is fine, but unfortunately my bench leads me to think that many 2MiB pages are used and not one 1GiB page. Here is the explanation:

This bench randomly access the allocated memory through pointer's chasing: a first step fills the memory to enable pointer chasing (each cell points to another cell) and in a second step the bench navigates through the memory using

```
pointer = *pointer;
```

Using the `perf_event_open` system call, I am counting data TLB read misses for the second step of the bench only. When the memory allocated size is 64MiB, I count a very small number, 0,01 % of my 6400000 memory accesses, of data TLB read misses. All the accesses are saved in the TLB. In other words, 64MiB of memory can be kept in the TLB. As soon as the allocated memory size is greater than 64 MiB I see data tlb read misses. For a memory size equals to 128 MiB, I have 50% of my 6400000 memory accesses that missed in the TLB. 64MiB appears to be the size that can fit in the TLB and 64MiB = 32 entries (as reportd below) * 2MiB pages. I conclude that I am not using 1GiB pages but 2MiB ones.

Can you see any explanation for that behavior ?

Moreover, the `cpuid` tool, reports the following about the tlb on my system:

```
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x5a: data TLB: 2M/4M pages, 4-way, 32 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x55: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 7 entries
      0xb0: instruction TLB: 4K, 4-way, 128 entries
      0xca: L2 TLB: 4K, 4-way, 512 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
```

As you can see, there is no information about 1GiB pages. How many such pages can be cached in the TLB ?

Comment: can you use `mmap ( ..., MAP_ANON | MAP_HUGETLB)`?

Comment: @abligh it fails with "Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: Do you have huge page support compiled into your kernel?

Comment: Yes and morover, I am able to successfully allocate memory from th hugtlbfs but I appears I still have tlb misses whereas I am only allocating and using 256MB of memory

Comment: `cat /proc/meminfo` will tell you if you are really allocating huge pages (as will `/proc/PID/maps` I think). Per http://lwn.net/Articles/375096/ you could try the `shm_get` interface. Can you allocate 256MB of memory and still use a 1GB page through hugetlbfs? Won't you need to allocate 1GB?

Comment: it seems that hug pages are allocated according to /proc/meminfo. Regarding an allocation of 256MB through 1GB pages in a hugetlbfs, yes I thought it was possible but I am not sure ...

Comment: I'm wondering whether you are getting smaller hugepages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68878/discussion-between-manuel-selva-and-abligh).

Comment: Could you post up your complete testbench code please, including the `perf_event_open` call in particular? I happen to have access to a Linux machine _(kernel 3.11, however)_ with a processor that supposedly supports this page-size, and that can easily allocate 10 of them. I'd love to take a shot at this.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist https://github.com/ManuelSelva/c4fun/blob/master/mem_load/mem_load.c

Comment: @ManuelSelva Thank you, I'll try it out later today and if I get anywhere on this older system I'll share what I get.

Comment: @ManuelSelva Alright - I'm booted in my system with kernel args `hugepagesz=1G hugepages=10 default_hugepagesz=1G`. I cloned your project and `make`'d it with errors, but luckily `mem_load` did build cleanly. What arguments do you invoke `mem_load` with? Because whatever I do it seems the number of hugepages does not drop from 10, at least not according to `hugeadm --pool-list` or `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/710870/

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's kinda related, and I even saw it but.... But on account of what I discovered in my answer below (_"CPU supports 1GB pages"_ does not imply _"TLB supports 1GB page entries"_), your question and [comments](http://superuser.com/questions/710870/which-cpus-support-1gb-pages#comment925856_722368) need to be edited. AFAIK: On all systems pre-Westmere and some Westmere+ systems, the feature is absent; On Westmere processors with the feature, there's zero 1GB TLB entries (so no TLB miss reduction); And on post-Westmere systems with the feature there are four 1GB TLB entries.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist You are absolutely correct. I think I will just cross-link that post to this one. Thanks for the in-depth analysis! I assumed the TLB would support whatever the rest of the MMU supported, and was wrong.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think any normal person (Even myself) would think that Intel would have the decency of making the TLB support 1GB pages too if they're advertising "support for 1GB large pages". I don't really fault you - I was surprised too.

Comment: The way I see it then, on Westmere, the only advantage to having 1GB pages, is to reduce the amount of memory needed for the page tables themselves. Specifically, Linux x86_64's direct mapping of all physical memory, and I suppose any userspace program crazy enough to `mmap` multiples of 1GB.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## TL;DR

*You (specifically, your processor)* cannot benefit from 1GB pages in this scenario, but your code is correct without modifications on systems that can.

## Long version

I followed these steps to attempt to reproduce your problem.

```
My System: Intel Core i7-4700MQ, 32GB RAM 1600MHz, Chipset H87
```

1. `svn co https://github.com/ManuelSelva/c4fun.git`
2. `cd c4fun.git/trunk`
3. `make`. Discovered a few dependencies were needed. Installed them. Build failed, but `mem_load` did build and link, so did not pursue the rest further.
4. Rebooted the system, appending at GRUB time to the boot arguments the following:

   ```
    hugepagesz=1G hugepages=10 default_hugepagesz=1G
   ```

   which reserves 10 1GB pages.
5. `cd c4fun.git/trunk/mem_load`
6. Ran several tests using `memload`, in random-access pattern mode and pinning it to core 3, which is something that isn't 0 (the bootstrap processor).

   - `./mem_load -a rand -c 3 -m 1073741824 -i 1048576`

     This resulted in approximately nil TLB misses.
   - `./mem_load -a rand -c 3 -m 10737418240 -i 1048576`

     This resulted in approximately 60% TLB misses. On a hunch I did
   - `./mem_load -a rand -c 3 -m 4294967296 -i 1048576`

     This resulted in approximately nil TLB misses. On a hunch I did
   - `./mem_load -a rand -c 3 -m 5368709120 -i 1048576`

     This resulted in approximately 20% TLB misses.

At this point I downloaded the `cpuid` utility. It gave me this for `cpuid -1 | grep -i tlb`:

```
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
      0xc1: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 8-way, 1024 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
```

As you can see, my TLB has 4 entries for 1GB pages. This explains well my results: For 1GB and 4GB arenas, the 4 slots of the TLB are entirely sufficient to satisfy all accesses. For 5GB arenas and random-access pattern mode, 4 of the 5 pages only can be mapped through the TLB, so chasing a pointer into the remaining one will cause a miss. The probability of chasing a pointer into the unmapped page is 1/5, so we expect a miss rate of 1/5 = 20% and we get that. For 10GB, 4/10 pages are mapped and 6/10 aren't so the miss rate will be 6/10=60%, and we got that.

So your code works without modifications on my system at least. Your code does not appear to be problematic then.

I then did some research on CPU-World, and while not all CPUs are listed with TLB geometry data, some are. The only one I saw that matched your cpuid printout exactly (there could be more) is the [Xeon Westmere-EP X5650](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20X5650%20-%20AT80614004320AD%20%28BX80614X5650%29.html); CPU-World does not explicitly say that the Data TLB0 has entries for 1GB pages, but does say the processor has "1 GB large page support".

I then did more research and finally nailed it. An author at RealWorldTech makes an (admittedly, I must yet find a source for this) off-hand comment in the discussion of the memory subsystem of Sandy Bridge. It reads [as follows](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/7/):

> After address generation, uops will access the DTLB to translate from a virtual to a physical address, in parallel with the start of the cache access. The DTLB was mostly kept the same, but the support for 1GB pages has improved. **Previously, Westmere added support for 1GB pages, but fragmented 1GB pages into many 2MB pages since the TLB did not have any 1GB page entries.** Sandy Bridge adds 4 dedicated entries for 1GB pages in the DTLB.

(Emphasis added)

## Conclusion

Whatever nebulous concept *"CPU supports 1GB pages"* represents, Intel thinks it does not imply *"TLB supports 1GB page entries"*. I'm afraid that you will not be able to use 1GB pages on an Intel Westmere processor to reduce the number of TLB misses.

That, or Intel is hoodwinking us by distinguishing *huge pages* (in the TLB) from *large pages*.

Comment: Thanks for your research and answer, and thanks stackoverflow ;-)